# How to delete rows from UITableView based on date

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView displaying entries, and an underlying array with those entries. Now I want to delete all entries that are older than a specific number of days.

My question is, what would be the most performant way to do that?

- go through the array, compare the dates and delete all old entries and then delete their corresponding rows in the tableView

or

- go through the tableView's rows, compare the dates and then delete the rows and their corresponding entries in the array

Does anyone know the best way to do this? Is there even a "best" way?

Comment: go through the array, compare and delete the entries, and it should be reflect on the tableview.

Comment: Just filter the array by comparing the objects int and remove those object which is beyond your limitations

Comment: What the size of this array? we are talking about >500 entries or more than that?

Comment: Just use predicate to filter array which is greater than your specific date, store it in another array or in same array and reload tableview. Don't need to delete records. As per you get new array with greater than specific date, your tableview also get new records without displaying older one.

Comment: Update the Array first by removing the unnecessary objects, then don't forget to reload the tableView by calling reloadData.

Comment: The array should not be a lot bigger than a few hundred entries. But the consensus seems to be to delete from the array and then call reloadData, so I'll go with that.

Comment: Sort by recent date and remove the last things, which is old